# Can I use an Angular Directive to create 3 separate dropdowns populated with different arrays from one controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-options

Lets say I have 3 dropdowns on a view. The three dropdowns are formatted the same, however they get their data from 3 separate arrays from the same controller.

```
<!-- Adults -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Adults (12+)</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedAdult" ng-options="adult for adult in adults" ng-change="populatePassengerCombos()">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Children -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Children (2-11)</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedChild" ng-options="child for child in children" ng-change="populatePassengerCombos()">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Infants -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Infants (0-1)</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedInfant" ng-options="infant for infant in infants" ng-change="populatePassengerCombos()">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can create a directive like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angular10App')
.directive('passengerCombo', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/common/passengerCombo/passengerCombo.html',
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {

        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.label;
        }
    };
});
```

Template:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>{{label}}</label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="" ng-options="" ng-change="populatePassengerCombos()">
    </select>
</div>
```

And pass it the label like this:

```
<passenger-combo label="Adult (12+)"></passenger-combo>

<passenger-combo label="Children (2-11)"></passenger-combo>

<passenger-combo label="Infants (0-1)"></passenger-combo>
```

But how would I get it to use the correct ng-model and ng-options? ng-change is the same for all three.

Here is the controller:

```
//Adult combo
var maxAdults = maxPassengers;
var minAdults = 1;
$scope.adults = $filter('range')($scope.adults, minAdults, maxAdults);
$scope.selectedAdult = 1;

//Children combo    
var maxChildren = maxPassengers - $scope.selectedAdult;
var minChildren = 0;
$scope.children = $filter('range')($scope.children, minChildren, maxChildren);
$scope.selectedChild = 0;

//Infant combo    
var maxInfants = $scope.selectedAdult;
var minInfants = 0;
$scope.infants = $filter('range')($scope.infants, minInfants, maxInfants);
$scope.selectedInfant = 0;
```

range is a custom filter that returns an array which populates the dropdowns. It works as expected.

EDIT:
I got the ng-model and ng-options working by changing to the following:

HTML

```
<passenger-combo label="Adult (12+)" ng-model="selectedAdult" items="adults"></passenger-combo>

<passenger-combo label="Children (2-11)" ng-model="selectedChild" items="children"></passenger-combo>

<passenger-combo label="Infants (0-1)" ng-model="selectedInfant" items="infants"></passenger-combo>
```

Directive

```
angular.module('angular10App')
.directive('passengerCombo', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/common/passengerCombo/passengerCombo.html',
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.label = attrs.label;
        }
    };
});
```

Template

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{label}}</label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="item for item in items">
    </select>
</div>
```

But I have no idea how to get the shared function working (populatePassengerCombos())????

EDIT
I have tried this but it still does not work. Added to directive scope

```
scope: {
            populatePassengerCombos: '&'
        },
```

and passed into the directive

```
<passenger-combo label="Adult (12+)" ng-model="selectedAdult" items="adults" populate-passenger-combos="populatePassengerCombos()"></passenger-combo>
```

Here is the function populatePassengerCombos

```
//Populate passenger combos
    $scope.populatePassengerCombos = function () {

        //Adults combo
        $scope.adults = $filter('range')($scope.adults, minAdults, (maxPassengers - $scope.selectedChild - $scope.selectedInfant));

        //Children combo
        $scope.children = $filter('range')($scope.children, minChildren, (maxPassengers - $scope.selectedAdult - $scope.selectedInfant));

        //Infant combo
        $scope.infants = $filter('range')($scope.infants, minInfants, (maxPassengers - $scope.selectedAdult - $scope.selectedChild));
        if ($scope.infants.length > 5) {
            $scope.infants = $filter('range')($scope.infants, minInfants, 4);
        }
        if ($scope.selectedAdult < 4) {
            $scope.infants = $filter('range')($scope.infants, minInfants, $scope.selectedAdult);
        }
        if ((maxPassengers - $scope.selectedAdult - $scope.selectedChild) === 0) {
            $scope.infants = $filter('range')($scope.infants, minInfants, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the populatePassengerCombos() function a parameter that corresponds to the appropriate age group. IE: 
     populatePassengerCombo('adults')
or 
     populatePassengerCombo('children')

and then in that function just use conditionals

```
 $scope.populatePassengerCombo = function(age) {
  if (age  == 'adult') {
   do something
  }
  else if (age == 'children') {
    do something else
  }
}
```

Is that what you are askign?

Comment: When populatePassengerCombo is called it populates all three combos at once. There are conditions on what is in each combo determined by what is selected in the other two.

Comment: Can you copy and paste just that function? I'm not sure I get it yet.

Comment: Do you want all three to be called? If so pass all three parameters and handle that event in the controller depending on what was passed

Comment: I have added the function that updates the three combos